# new to windows application development, need some advice

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, webkit

Hi
I'm starting windows application development on windows7 with C++. ( or C#/Java if necessary ).

The application in mind right now is a window that has a inner frame (kind like a iframe) displaying a web page in it, and to have the outer and inner frame be able to communicate ( ie. the webpage pass a message to the outer frame, possibly by JavaScript, and the outer frame recognize the message and starts the computer's camera ).

It would be something like this
http://html5demos.com/postmessage2
except that the outer frame is a windows application instead of a webpage.
Preferably, the inner frame displaying the web page is powered by web-kit.

I really don't have much experience so I was wondering if such thing is possible and where to start.
Any advice or resource is welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest C# rather than C++ (and I'm a C++ veteran).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen projects use the status bar to communicate with Javascript in an embedded browser.

RichHtml4Eclipse is such a project ; while no longer in development, it demonstrates the general approach. Events with structured data are raised by changing the status text, which native code on the outside can pick up and deserialize. Javascript methods may be called on the code in the page by using the method calls provided on the browser control.

I would support the comment that encourages you to avoid C++. There are WebKit bindings for both Java and C# ; in my experience, Java has the edge in portability but C# / .NET makes for an easier experience when developing GUI components.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you take a look at [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/). It is cross-platform, comes with QtCreator - a nice IDE, and can be easily integrated with [WebKit](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKit) (in fact, WebKit is started by KDE, which is based on Qt).

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Windows and aren't concerned with portability, using .NET could much quicker. Perhaps [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379558%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) would be of some use.